# Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2012 with Access! Can't get image url's to load into picture box

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am currently learning VB and my task is to do a quiz that stores details of the user and also stores the questions and answers. The problem I'm having is that I've stored URL's in the database but I'm unable to turn these into the actual images using the picturebox tool.

Here is my code to do this:

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbprovider As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dbsource As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    dbprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbsource = "Data Source = C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Assignment2.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
    con.Open()

    MsgBox("open")
    sql = "Select * from questions_new Where ID = 1"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Question")

    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("Question").Rows
        Label1.Text = (row.Item("Question"))
        Label2.Text = (row.Item("Answer_1"))
        Label3.Text = (row.Item("Answer_2"))
        Label4.Text = (row.Item("Answer_3"))
        Label5.Text = (row.Item("Answer_4"))
        PictureBox1.Image = (row.Item("Img"))

    Next row

    ' con.Close()
    'MsgBox("closed")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `PictureBox1.Image` has a type of `System.Drawing.Image`.

The property that you want is `PictureBox1.ImageLocation` which is a string that can be a local path or a URL.